# Excel VBA: Worksheet Double-click event won't run when worksheet is protected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with the running of a worksheet event (`BeforeDoubleClick`) while the worksheet is protected. (In fact, the whole workbook is protected.) The entire event won't run, so I can't run `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` as the first line in the worksheet, even before the event makes its changes. For completeness's sake, here's my code, though it doesn't even run, so it might not be a factor:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Call ToggleReceiptSetting(Target, "statements")
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

If I unprotect the worksheet manually, the event runs. Does anyone have a solution or a reason why Excel won't run this if the worksheet is protected? Is there a way to make it run without unprotecting the sheet before the event runs?

Comment: Can't reproduce that issue. If I use your sub in a fresh workbook with a protected sheet 1 and a protected workbook (protected with an empty password) your code works, and the event is executed. Are you sure that the event isn't executed? Test it by using a break point on `ActiveSheet.Unprotect` in the debugger.

Comment: If 'the worksheet is protected' the user may not be allowed to *select* (aka *click*) on a cell. If they cannot click on a cell then they cannot double-click on a cell so no trigger is launched. Have you tried this will `Cancel = True` as the **first** line? This cancels any in-cell editing that may be attempted.

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint in and putting `Cancel = True` as the first line, but neither worked. I also have the cell (and all others like it) not marked as Locked or Hidden. When I click on Review->Protect Sheet, I can see I have "Select unlocked cells" checked. Indeed, I can click around and even edit the contents of the cells I'm trying to double-click, just not run the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Stupid me. The reason it wasn't running is because the cell was getting its data from a predefined list. So whenever I clicked on the cell, it would automatically enter into "list mode" and so wouldn't run the doubleclick event. I never got the chance to double-click since one click was enough to activate the "list mode"!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I needed to solve it without removing the list.

I found the way to do that:

When protecting the sheet, if you "allow" the last two options (Objects and Scenarios) the list won't open when clicking the list-cell with the sheet protection activated and, therefore, it will allow the DoubleClick Event to run.

Of course, you can program it also in vba:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("YOUR_RANGE_HERE")) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE"

    'YOUR_CODE_HERE

    ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, _
            AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
            AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, Password:="YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE"

End If

End Sub
```

Please, note that in the protection statement I have included / allowed other options that you may want to exclude. Check what of these options you need (you can use the macro recorder in case you need it, but do not forget to click the objets and scenarios options).